# empty Response when send data to other page

Tags: php, jquery

i have problem on jquery Response is empty,

```
<input id="bill_customer" name="bill_customer" onChange="showBalance()"/>
<span id="CustomerBalance" style="color:#F00"></span>
```

here i have input type to insert customer name and send request to other page to get the balance of this customer, and insert it to span that have id name `CustomerBalance`

when i send requst to this page code to get balance

```
$name = $_POST['name'];


$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer where customer_Name ='$name' and customer_StorID='$ausers_ID'";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
echo $row['customer_Balance'];
}
```

we must send me the balance but i cannot get it. why!!

this is function jquery

```
function showBalance(){
 $.ajax({
  url: "getBalance.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: { name : $("#bill_customer").val() },
  dataType: "html",
  success : function(data){
   $("#CustomerBalance").html(data);
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: does your query return result..? what does console show... for ajax ..?

Comment: if you access `getBalance.php` directly, with `$_POST` parameters, do you get results?

Comment: add `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the beginning of `PHP` code, and you may see what the error is.

Comment: yes i get result from my query when put it on phpmyadmin, and i can send post to getBalance.php on variable name, but i canot get result

Comment: Try using `$_GET` temporarily instead of `$_POST` to test getBalance.php file. Also note that the variable `$ausers_ID` is undefined ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something like that? :

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
*$balances = array();*

*$sql = "SELECT customer_Balance FROM customer where customer_Name ='$name' and customer_StorID='$ausers_ID'";*
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    *$balances[] = $row['customer_Balance'];*
}
*echo json_encode($balances);*
```

You must try to use a field name in SELECT statements ever you can, because it is much fast.

You must use mysqli (or PDO) functions too, because the mysql can be removed in the future (and is very insecure).

And, finally, you can use functions like fetch_all so you can omit the while. Something like that:

```
echo json_encode($query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```